# is there any way to automate policykeys creation in identityexperienceframework under azure Ad B2C tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is there any way to create Azure AD B2C PolicyKeys under identityexperienceframework using either the APIs or using PowerShell.

i have tried in portal by creating manually..it is working well as expected.but now i'm trying to create through powershell..amazingly i'm not finding any way either restapi or powershell  **Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://main.b2cadmin.ext.azure.com/api/trustframework?tenantId=$TenantID&overwriteIfExists=true" -Method POST -Body $strBody -ContentType "application/xml" -Headers $htHeaders -UseBasicParsing**
the above url is used to uploadpolices..
is there any similar way to create policykeys as well in identityexperienceframework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, you can use the https://main.b2cadmin.ext.azure.com/api/Jwks/PutSecret?tenantId=&storageReferenceId=&keyUsage= to create policykeys.

```
Method : Put
URL : https://main.b2cadmin.ext.azure.com/api/Jwks/PutSecret?tenantId=<your Azure AD B2C tenant id>&storageReferenceId=<your key name>&keyUsage=<you key usage> 
Header
Authorization : Bearer token
Content-type : application/xml

Body
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no officially supported way yet. But the feature is under development.